# Многопоточность java, работа с классом

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть переменная `volatile static int number` , с её помощью один из потоков `counter1` увеличивает её на 1, а второй поток `printer1` печатает значение этой переменной. Но по заданию мне нужно создать класс `storage`, который будет хранить значение переменной увеличенной в потоке `counter1`, а затем поток `printer1` должен считывать значение этой переменной из класса `storage`. Я не совсем понимаю как мне сделать так, что бы переменная записывалась в классе `storage`,а поток принтер считал из неё значение. Сейчас у меня принтер считает значение переменной из потока `counter1`

```
public class Main {
   volatile static int number = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread printer = new Thread( new Printer1());
        printer.start();
      Thread counter = new Thread( new Counter1());
     counter.start();


    }

    static  class Counter1 implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Счётчик начинает считать");
            starCounter();
        }

        private synchronized void starCounter(){
            try{
                while (number < 50) {
                    number++;
                    System.out.println("считаем значение");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }catch (InterruptedException exc){
                System.out.println("Поток " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " был прерван");
            }

        }
    }

    static class Printer1 implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("ПРИНТЕР НАЧИНАЕТ ПЕЧАТАТЬ");
            starPrinter();
        }

        private synchronized void starPrinter(){
            int localNumber = number;
            while ( number < 50){
                if ( localNumber != number){
                    System.out.println("ПЕЧАТАЕМ " + number);
                    localNumber = number;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя просто так записывать значение переменной в одном потоке и читать в другом. Для этого существует понятие `Atomic`, то есть атомарной переменной. То есть в один и тот же момент времени в нее можно или только читать или только писать. `volatile` вас не спасет.

Надо сделать что-то типа:

```
class Storage {
    AtomicInteger counter=new AtomicInteger(0);

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter.get();
    }

    public int incrementCounter() {
       return counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Теперь там где вы делаете инкремент, надо вставить `storage.incrementCounter()`, предварительно надо задекларировать класс `Storage` типа `Storage storage=new Storage();`